# Cannot install pytest from requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pytest, pytest-cov

I am using `pip3` to install modules for my python project. My `requirements.txt` looks like this:

```
urllib3==1.22
cx_freeze==6.0b1
pytest==3.2.2
pytest-cov==2.5.1
pytest-dependency==0.2
```

I clearly have `pytest` added to my requirements but when I run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` it cannot find `pytest` and shows the following exception:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-y300zryw/pytest-dependency/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pytest_dependency
  File "/tmp/pip-build-y300zryw/pytest-dependency/pytest_dependency.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pytest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'
```

When I manually do a `pip3 install pytest` and then run my requirements file, it works fine.

Why does pytest not install from `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for your version of `pytest-cov` need `pytest==3.4.2`
so simple edit the `requirements.txt` to

```
urllib3==1.22
cx_freeze==6.0b1
pytest==3.4.2
pytest-cov==2.5.1
pytest-dependency==0.2
```

first time it help me, but now it work even for 3.2.2

`$ workon ptest`

```
(ptest) $ python -V
Python 3.5.3
```

look on installed

```
(ptest) $ pip freeze
attrs==17.4.0
coverage==4.5.1
pluggy==0.6.0
py==1.5.2
six==1.11.0
```

install

```
(ptest) $ cat requirements.txt 
urllib3==1.22
cx_freeze==6.0b1
pytest==3.2.2
pytest-cov==2.5.1
pytest-dependency==0.2

(ptest) $ pip install -r requirements.txt 
Collecting urllib3==1.22 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cx_freeze==6.0b1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Collecting pytest==3.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached pytest-3.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytest-cov==2.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached pytest_cov-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytest-dependency==0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/user/.virtualenvs/ptest/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest==3.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.4.33 in /home/user/.virtualenvs/ptest/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest==3.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied: coverage>=3.7.1 in /home/user/.virtualenvs/ptest/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest-cov==2.5.1->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Installing collected packages: urllib3, cx-freeze, pytest, pytest-cov, pytest-dependency
Successfully installed cx-freeze-6.0b1 pytest-3.2.2 pytest-cov-2.5.1 pytest-dependency-0.2 urllib3-1.22
```

check it

```
(ptest) $ pip freeze
attrs==17.4.0
coverage==4.5.1
cx-Freeze==6.0b1
pluggy==0.6.0
py==1.5.2
pytest==3.2.2
pytest-cov==2.5.1
pytest-dependency==0.2
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.2
```

Comment: I just did that but still see the same issue.

Comment: do you use virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, I activate the venv and then run 'pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: try to run command `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside your virtualenv

Comment: I am inside my venv while I run that but I get the same issue.

Comment: i added full text of testing in my local machine may be it help you

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the version of `pytest-dependency` you have - 0.2 is way too old. You can't install `pytest-dependency==0.2` in one pass with `pytest`:

```
$ pip install pytest-dependency==0.2 pytest
```

will fail.

However, this issue was fixed in 0.3 version, see [issue #13](https://github.com/RKrahl/pytest-dependency/issues/13) and [issue #14](https://github.com/RKrahl/pytest-dependency/issues/14) closed. So just bump `pytest-dependency` to the current version and you're good to go:

```
urllib3==1.22
cx_freeze==6.0b1
pytest==3.2.2
pytest-cov==2.5.1
pytest-dependency==0.3.2
```

Comment: thanks! I updated pytest to 3.4.2 and pytest-dependency to 0.3.2 and it worked! I could only accept one answer, so accepted Bear Brown's. Thank you both.

Comment: no worries, although his answer does not solve your issue at all ^^

Comment: OP should accept the answer that solved the OP's question (ie this one).  If OP had done so, would have saved me time.